# Como Validar Logeo sql server en store procedure con variables de entrada

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

```
>      Buenas noches quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy realizando una
>      validación : Bueno la verdad estoy realizando un Logeo que todos los usuarios van tener 3 intentos al ingresar con lenguaje c# con **sql
> server y procedimiento almacenado para el logeo**.  Lo que quiero que se realiza es
> que si el usuario y contraseña es correcta ingrese  , Cuando el
> usuario ingrese su contraseña mala solo le quede 2 intentos y si sigue
> intentando le queda 1 intento pero si en su ultimo intento sigue
> escribiendo mal se bloquea el usuario y ya no ingresa . Para eso en la
> pagina se va mostrar los errores o cuanto intentos le quedan para
> realizar eso lo estoy realizando en sql server como estoy realizando
> un store procedure pero no me logra salir en sql server 
> 
>      1. Que si es verdad el usuario y password que me muestre un select*from usuario y en el campo intentosusuario nuevamente sea 3
>     2. que si es falso el usuario o contraseña el campo de intentossuario que es 3  se reste -1  y asi sucesivamente  y se
> muestre select*from usuario
>      3. Que si en el campo intentosusuario es = 0 que muestre en el campo estadousuario salga como ='bloqueado' select*from usuario
```

> `no se si me entiendan no soy bueno explicando`

en sql server esta en mi tabla :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[usuario](
        [Idusuario] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [username] [varchar](200) NULL,
        [llave] [varchar](200) NULL,
        [Nombres] [varchar](350) NULL,
        [Apellidos] [varchar](350) NULL,
        [sexo] [varchar](1) NULL,
        [IDUsuarioPerfil] [varchar](1) NULL,
        [EstadoUsuario] [varchar](20) NULL,
        [IntentosUsuario] [varchar](10) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]


GO
INSERT [dbo].[usuario] ([Idusuario], [username], [llave], [Nombres], [Apellidos], [sexo], [IDUsuarioPerfil], [EstadoUsuario], [IntentosUsuario]) VALUES (1, N'pflores', N'222222', N'Pierro Joshep', N'Flores Espinoza', N'H', N'1', N'ACT', N'3')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[usuario] ([Idusuario], [username], [llave], [Nombres], [Apellidos], [sexo], [IDUsuarioPerfil], [EstadoUsuario], [IntentosUsuario]) VALUES (2, N'Syaringano', N'222222', N'Sandra', N'Yaringaño Vargas', N'M', N'2', N'ACT', N'3')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[usuario] ([Idusuario], [username], [llave], [Nombres], [Apellidos], [sexo], [IDUsuarioPerfil], [EstadoUsuario], [IntentosUsuario]) VALUES (3, N'Dyllescas', N'222222', N'Daniel', N'Yllescas Romani', N'H', N'3', N'ACT', N'3')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[usuario] OFF
GO


Yo creado un procedimiento almacenado que tiene dos variables de entrada que son : 
username y llave
```

Este es mi Procedimiento almacenado :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[LoginUsuario]
@username varchar(250),
@llave varchar(250)
as
begin

if exists(select * from usuario where username=@username and llave=@llave and EstadoUsuario='ACT' and IntentosUsuario <=(0))
begin
  update colegio..usuario set IntentosUsuario=3 where username=@username
select idusuario, nombres + ' ' + apellidos as 'Nombres',idusuarioperfil,IntentosUsuario ,EstadoUsuario from usuario where username=@username and llave=@llave and EstadoUsuario='ACT'
end

  else if  exists(select * from usuario where username<>@username or llave<>@llave and EstadoUsuario='ACT' and IntentosUsuario<=(0))
begin
declare @num int,@numerorestar int
set @num=(select intentosusuario from usuario where username=@username or llave=@llave and EstadoUsuario='ACT')
set @numerorestar=(@num-1)
update usuario set IntentosUsuario=@numerorestar  where username=@username or llave=@llave and EstadoUsuario='ACT'
update usuario set EstadoUsuario = case  when IntentosUsuario<=0 then 'BLOQUEADO' Else 'ACT' end 
select idusuario=0, nombres + ' ' + apellidos as 'Nombres',idusuarioperfil,IntentosUsuario,EstadoUsuario from usuario where username=@username or llave=@llave

end

end
```

El problema es cuando ingreso el usuario o contraseña Correcta me sale este error :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

El problema parece ser esta sentencia:

```
set @num=(select intentosusuario from usuario where username=@username or llave=@llave and EstadoUsuario='ACT')
```

Debería retornar un registro pero está recuperando más. Ejecutala individualmente con los datos con los que te digo el error para verificar la lógica. El problema pareciera ser el OR.

Fijate esta sentencia:

```
select intentosusuario from usuario where username='pflores' or llave='222222' and EstadoUsuario='ACT'
```

El retorno es

```
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Efectivamente si te fijás devuelve 3 registros cuando en realidad debería devolver un único registro por el usuario que buscas. Tenés dos problemas, por un lado el OR en realidad es AND y además no estas considerando el NULL de intentosusuario, te sugiero esta modificación:

```
select isnull(intentosusuario,0) from usuario where username='pflores' AND llave='222222' and EstadoUsuario='ACT'
```

Comment: una consulta pero mi logia esta bien plazmado en el sql server lo saque el or pero igual me sigue jalando ese mismo problema

Comment: Efectivamente el problema era el que te decía, amplio la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Buenos lo Solione pero no se si sea lo correcto pero me resulto dejo el codigo:
Lo que realize es primero que en un if valide si existe o no el usuario si en caso existe  lo que va ser 1 que sus intentos de logró ingresen con 3 
Pero si en caso no existe el usuario en una variable estoy almacenado solo el número de intentos y restando 1 del mismo usuario  pero si en caso el número de intentos es menor o igual a 0 que modifique el campo estado usuario a bloqueado y al final después del enf solo puse que se muestre todo la tabla según el usuario que ingresen .

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[LoginUsuario]
@username varchar(250),
@llave varchar(250)
as
begin

if exists(select*from usuario where username=@username and llave=@llave)
begin
--select*from usuario where username=@username

update usuario set IntentosUsuario=3 where username=@username
end
else if  exists (select *from usuario where username<>@username)
begin

declare @num int,@numerorestar int
set @num=(select intentosusuario from usuario where username=@username  and EstadoUsuario='ACT')
set @numerorestar=(@num-1)
update usuario set IntentosUsuario=@numerorestar  where username=@username  and EstadoUsuario='ACT'
update usuario set EstadoUsuario=(case when (IntentosUsuario<='0') then 'BLO' else 'ACT'end)
end
select*from usuario where username=@username
end
```

Comment: Tienes razón @sstan ahotita editó mi respuesta . pero no se si esta bien si así se puede hacer pero me salio si hay algún nueva respuesta con mucho gusto

Comment: @sstan ya edite mi respuesta